# Dart List.fold vs List.reduce type inference

Tags: list, dart, reduce, static-analysis, fold

**Using Dart 2.14.2 I ran the following code**

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  var a = <int>[1, 2, 3];

  final foldValue = a.fold(0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element);
  final reduceValue = a.reduce((previousValue, element) => previousValue + element);
}
```

for the line containing `foldValue` the analyzer give me the following error :

```
Error: The operator '+' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
```

without giving any error for the line containing `reduceValue`.

**My question is: what makes List.fold raises such error while List.reduce doesn't?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `List.fold` problem is a well-known limit of the Dart type inference algorithm.
Since you haven't provided a type argument to `fold`, the type inference infers static type for each argument *independently*, then try to combine them to find a valid type argument to `fold` itself.
The two arguments are inferred independently *and with no type hint*.

The `0` argument is easy, it has type `int`.

The `(previousValue, element) => previousValue + element` function is harder.
The algorithm has no clue to what type the first parameter should be. It should be `T`, the type parameter of `fold`, but we don't know `T` yet. It can't use the body, because it can't type analyze the body before it has a type for the parameters (and even if it could, there are many parameter types which would make the body valid; `dynamic`, `int`, `num`, and `double` are potential candidates, and there can be more user types which allow you to add `int` to them.)

With no hint from the outside, the type inference uses the top-type and gets `(Object? previousValue, int element) => ...`. Then it fails to accept `previousValue + element`.

The reason `reduce` doesn't fail is that it has all the necessary information. Both parameters must have type `int`, the element type of the list.

Comment: For reference about this well-known problem with `List.fold`, etc., see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/731.