# Generic type inference in function from lists

Tags: dart, generics

I'm working on some generic list utility functions and there seems to be an issue with the type inference for a generic function when the primary variables are lists. This is demonstrated with the following code:

```dart
List<T> combine<T>(List<T> a, List<T> b, T Function(T a, T b) combiner) {
  final list = <T>[];
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++) {
    list.add(combiner(a[i], b[i]));
  }
  return list;
}

void main() {
  final a = [5, 8];
  final b = [7, -3];
  final c = combine(a, b, (a, b) => a + b); // Error

  print(c); 
  // Expected: [12, 5]
}
```

When I use this code as-is, the type inference within the lambda sets `a` and `b` to be `Object?`, which results in the following error message:

> The operator '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
> Try adding a null check to the target ('!').

Doing what the error message says changes the message to the following:

> The operator '+' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
> Try defining the operator '+'.

The issue obviously is that type inference is assigning the parameters to `Object?` instead of the expected `int`. This can be worked around by either typing the parameters or explicitly passing the generic type to the function:

```dart
final c = combine(a, b, (int a, int b) => a + b);
// OR
final c = combine<int>(a, b, (a, b) => a + b);
```

However, that's an added level of verbosity that I don't want to have to force the users of these utility functions to have to do (not to mention it will be a support issue when I have to explain to them to do this). Is there a way to change the function signature to make it so type inference works as expected?

Comment: Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/731.

Comment: @jamesdlin That's annoying, but good to know that I'm not just missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically [Dart List.fold vs List.reduce type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71526951/), but in your case you could sidestep the problem by making your function an extension method so that `T` is deduced from the receiver instead of from the arguments:

```dart
extension<T> on List<T> {
  List<T> combineWith(List<T> b, T Function(T a, T b) combiner) {
    final list = <T>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < length && i < b.length; i++) {
      list.add(combiner(this[i], b[i]));
    }
    return list;
  }
}

void main() {
  final a = [5, 8];
  final b = [7, -3];
  final c = a.combineWith(b, (a, b) => a + b); // Error

  print(c);
  // Expected: [12, 5]
}
```