# Type inference for simple generic method requires explicit type

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

I'm trying to understand if and how I can make the automatic type inference for a simple generic method work without having to explicitly provide a type anywhere.

For example, the following code doesn't compile and shows an error that *"The argument Object? can't be assigned to the parameter type num"*:

```
void test<V>(V value, Function(V value) doStuff){
  doStuff(value);
}


test(12, (v) => print('${10*v}'));
                            ^                            
         The argument Object? can't be assigned to the parameter type num
```

I have to do either

```
test(12, (int v) => print('${10*v}'));
```

or

```
test<int>(12, (v) => print('${10*v}'));
```

in order to make it work.

Why doesn't the Dart analyzer see that since `12` is an `int`, `v` must also be an `int`? Can I modify `test()` so that the automatic type inference understands that `v` is an `int`?

Comment: This is equivalent to the `List.fold` problem.  See [lrn's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71532840/).